# Can't show ip xfrm policy and state in android device?

Tags: android, ipsec

I have connected successully android device to strongswan server in ubuntu. I can see the policy (SP) and state (SA) with `ip xfrm` command in ubuntu but in android device I see nothing with `ip xfrm policy show` and `ip xfrm state show`. Anyone can help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this looking for evidence that ip-xfrm is available on Android, and apparently it is.  As for the "show" option, even in Ubuntu it appears to be unnecessary, so maybe Android doesn't support it.  What happens if you omit it and just use "ip xfrm state" or "ip xfrm policy"?  I don't know myself, since I haven't yet used Android, although I will at some point in the near future.

As an afterthought, I've seen an example that uses "ip -s xfrm policy", so maybe that's used in place of "show".

If you know C, maybe this will be useful as well:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iproute2/+/gingerbread/ip/xfrm.h